# How to pass current session information to phantom js?

Tags: javascript, spring, session, spring-security, phantomjs

I have Java Spring Security web application. I want to pass the current logged in user information to phantom js to login and capture a web page and save as pdf.

I have tried to pass the JSESSIONID to phantom js add cookie method.

```
var system = require('system');

// Web Address (URL) of the page to capture
var url = system.args[1];

// File name of the captured image
var file = system.args[2];

var cookieValue = system.args[3];

if (cookieValue && cookieValue !== "null") {
    phantom.addCookie({
        'name': 'JSESSIONID',
        'value': cookieValue,
        'domain': 'localhost:8081',
        'path': '/app'
    });
}
```

The rest of the java script opens the page and renders the screenshot. Using command line I am invoking phantom js and passing the arguments where to save, what to capture and the current logged in user's session id. What more information do I need to pass to let the server recognize the session? How to make it work without creating another session for the phantom js(which is working and I am getting the pdf)?

Comment: The port probably shouldn't be part of the domain.